# How to run another python script

Tags: python, operating-system

I would like to run another python script from within a python script, and terminate the originating script. I have tried the following:

```
import os
import os.path

print os.getcwd()
>>>home/pi/Gen

print os.path.exists('/home/pi/Gen/Binary2.py')
>>> True

os.execl('python',   '/home/pi/Gen/Binary2.py')
>>> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Is Python on your path?

Comment: `execfile(path_to_other_script)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the full path to the executable. You also need to provide, as the first argument, the executable itself:

```
import os

os.execl('/usr/bin/python', '/usr/bin/python', '/home/pi/Gen/Binary2.py')
```

You could also use the `p` variant to use the current process' path to find the executable:

```
os.execlp('python', 'python', '/home/pi/Gen/Binary2.py')
```

Comment: it would make more sense to use `sys.executable` instead of `'/usr/bin/python'` to ensure the same executable file is being used to execute both files.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: yeah, possibly, assuming that you actually want to use the same Python interpreter.

Comment: when _wouldn't_ you want to use the same python interpreter? Imbedding the python executable into an application so that it can run on a system without python installed couldn't work otherwise.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: The code in the answer is simply to demonstrate that the full path is required for `execl()`, and that the first argument is also needed. Using `execlp()` will execute whatever Python is on the path. And there are cases where you might want to use a different interpreter, e.g. a Python 3 process wants to run a Python 2 script. And running an embedded Python could still work if you knew the location of the executable (or it was on the path).

Answer (score -1):

Couple of methods:
you can try to add this to your code

```
execfile("Script-To-Execute.py")
```

Another method:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("Script-To-Execute.py", shell=True)
```